# Cannot access base class's protected constructor

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
class A
{
protected: 
    A(int i, int j) {}
};


class B: public A
{
    A Foo() { return A(1,2); }
};
```

It builds all right in Visual Studio 2010 but fails in 2015 because B::Foo() can not access A's protected constructor. What gives?

Comment: What's the exact error message? Copy and paste it.

Comment: @Cornstalks "C2248: cannot access protected member declared in class A"

Comment: ``A Foo()`` is trying to access the protected constructor, the fact that it is inside a derived class does not matter.